# Uniformly integrable martingale

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales, uniform-integrability

I have the following martingale.
$M_n=\exp\left(aB_n-\frac{1}{2}a^2n\right)$ for $n\geq0$ and $a\neq0$, $B_n$ is a BM.
I have to show that for $a>0$, 
$M_n\rightarrow0$ in probability.

Is $M_n$ uniformly integrable? I think its not but how can I prove it?

Any hints are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Write $$a \cdot B_n - \frac{1}{2} a^2 n = n \cdot \left( a \cdot \frac{B_n}{n}- \frac{1}{2}a^2 \right),$$ and use that $$\frac{B_n}{n} \to 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$ This actually even proves $M_n \to 0$ a.s.

Apply Vitali's convergence theorem in order to prove that $(M_n)_n$ is *not* uniformly integrable.

Comment: thank you again saz for you save my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does go to zero in probability.  All you need to do is to show that its expectation raised to a fractional power goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.  Since $aB_n/t \sim N(0,a^2n/t^2)$, $\exp(aB_n/t)$ is lognormal.  You can do the rest (this is your homework after all).

Comment: nice question though.

Comment: Why should the expectation converge to $0$? $(M_n)_n$ is a martingale...